# Get context from another CBV with Django

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-pagination

I would like to get your help in order to use context from a Django CBV in another CBV through `get_context_data()`.

**Objective:**

Basically, I have a django `ListView()` with `pagination`. I pick up the current page in `get_context_data()`. Then, I would like to edit an object, so I'm going to `UpdateView()`.

When I post the edit, it should return to the previous pagination. For example, if the object was on page 32, after the `POST request`, I need to be redirected to page 32.

**My code:**

```
class DocumentListView(AdminMixin, CustomListSearchView):
    """ Render the list of document """

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DocumentListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)

        actual_page = self.request.GET.get('page', 1)
        if actual_page:
            context['actual_page'] = actual_page
        return context

class DocumentFormView(CustomPermissionRequiredMixin, DocumentListView, UpdateView):

    def get_current_page(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DocumentListView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        actual_page = context['actual_page']
        return actual_page

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(DocumentFormView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        print(self.get_current_page())
        ...       
        return context

    def post(self, request, pk=None):
        ...
        return render(request, 'app/manage_document_form.html', context)
```

**Issue:**

I don't overcome to get the `actual_page` in my class `DocumentFormView`.

I got this issue :

> AttributeError: 'DocumentFormView' object has no attribute 'object'

I tried to add in my `post()` function :

```
self.object = self.get_object()
```

But it doesn't solve the issue.

Do you have any idea ?

Comment: This isn't at all what you want to do. It doesn't make any sense to use `super` like that, let alone have two separate methods calling two separate super methods. But quite apart from anything else, the data is coming from the request; if you need the value from the `page` parameter in the form view, it needs to be present in the request for that view.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Ok, but if I understand well the url according to my form view doesn't display any information from pagination in `ListView()`. So I don't see how I can pick up data from url through a `GET` request. In my `ListView()`, the url looks like this : `http://localhost:8000/crud/document/list/?page=72` and in my `UpdateView()` : `http://localhost:8000/crud/document/update/150/`

Comment: If it's not in the URL there is **no way** your view can get it. Your code is doubly mistaken in that case. You need to actually include the parameter in the URL you use for the form view.

Comment: Hum ok I have to see how I can do that. Thank you for your explanation anyway !